# how to cut a <ul> in two after a certain item using JQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, html-lists

I need to cut a list into two pieces with JQuery. Suppose I have the following list:

```
<ul>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li id="POI">item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
</ul>
```

I have tried using:

```
$("li#POI").after("</ul><ul>");
```

But it seems JQuery thinks I'm creating malformed HTML and does not insert the closing tag. instead it gives me this output:

```
<ul>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li id="POI">item</li>
  <ul></ul>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
</ul>
```

Please advise a way that helps me get the following output with JQuery:

```
<ul>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
  <li id="POI">item</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li>item</li>
  <li>item</li>
</ul>
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var splitPoint = $('#POI');
var list = splitPoint.parent();

$('<ul>').append(splitPoint.nextAll()).insertAfter(list);
```

If your list can be identified by an id or some other selector, then this can be simplified to:

```
$('<ul>').append($('#POI ~ li')).insertAfter('#listID');
```

Comment: Hmm, very nice. Maybe use `$('#POI').parent('ul')` in case there are other ul's?

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
var $poi = $('li#POI'),
    $ul = $poi.parent(),
    $items = $ul.children('li'),
    index = $items.index($poi),
    $itemsAfterPoi = $items.slice(index + 1);

$('<ul>').append($itemsAfterPoi).insertAfter($ul);
```

Comment: Eh, I like the code to say what it's doing... you can always turn it into a one-liner yourself. That said, I think @Anurag's answer is a lot more elegant :)

Answer (score 1):

This does the trick, for arbitrarily selected li elements.

```
$('li#POI').each( function () {
    $(this).parent().after( $(this).nextAll().wrapAll('<ul/>').parent() )
} )
```

An example use:

```
<ul>
<li>item 1</li>
<li>item 2</li>
<li>item 3</li>
<li>item 4</li>
<li>item 5</li>
<li>item 6</li>
<li>item 7</li>
<li>item 8</li>
<li>item 9</li>
<li>item 10</li>
</ul>
<script>
  $('ul :nth-child(3n)').each( function () { $(this).parent().after( $(this).nextAll().wrapAll('<ul/>').parent() ) } )
</script>
```

Comment: I believe you need to user .after( function() { ... } )

Comment: @Rob: doesn't seem to help; .after is supposed to be able to take a jQuery object as a parameter, anyway.

Comment: the expression `$(this).detach('~ li')` doesn't match anything, and returns the original `#POI` element back. Then `wrapAll` wraps a new `<ul>` around the `#POI` element, returning the `#POI` element again to preserve chaining. So the argument to the `after` function is `#POI` which now gets moved outside and after the original `<ul>`, leaving the new `<ul>` we created behind. To select following siblings, instead of `$(this).detach('~ li')`, try `$('#POI ~ li')`.

Comment: @Anurag: Fixed it!  I was looking for a more generic way to do it, in particular a way to select potentially more than one li and break up each list containing such an li.

Comment: I like the generic solution, very nice. tried an example using your code at http://jsfiddle.net/anurag/fwh53/